# Send email with content without using webservice in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, web-services, email

In my app I need to send the email to the mail id provided by the user with predefined content.

This has to be done internally without the interaction of the user i.e, as soon as user enters email id in the provided textfield and clicks send button, the mail with content has to sent to that mail-id.

Can this be done without using any webservice. Please help me out in this.

Thanks in advance,

Hanu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have achieved this with [SMKSMTPMessage](http://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/) - a library that allows you to send an email with attachments if required from code, without any user interaction required